# Dreamweaver / mysql 403 error

Tags: mysql, dreamweaver

When I try to connect to my mysql server (Debian linux, 192.168.0.90) in dreamweaver, I receive "HTTP Error Code 403 Forbidden"

Usually this is a sign that there has been an incorrect username or password entered. Not this time. It is correct but the server won't let me in. I can do all mysql commands through the mysql terminal and ssh is also available.

This is what I see: The red page is something I made and is not an error.

[image: THis is what I see. Page in background created by me.]

Comment: please don't use *dreamweaver*.

Comment: Why would a connection to a MySQL server throw an HTTP error?  Anyways, 403 is usually to do with file permissions, not necessarily authentication.

Comment: @Sajad I wasn't even aware that Dreamweaver was still around - a real blast from the past!

Comment: Why not use WorkBench?

Comment: What happens if you connect to the same page in your browser?

Answer (score 0):

This is a permissions error. It must be corrected.

In terminal, type:

> sudo chmod 777 /var/www && sudo chmod 777 /var/www/* && sudo chmod 777 /var/www/*/*

And press enter. It will execute.

then type:

> sudo chown -hR www-data /var/www

And press enter. That will execute.